# Left join with groups?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have 2 pyspark dfs  like this:

**minute_df**

```text
minute_time | val
----------------
00:00       | 4
00:01       | 5
```

**data_df**

```text
minute_time | currency | someOtherVal
------------------------------------
00:00       | USD      | 20
00:01       | USD      | 12
00:00       | CAD      | 14
```

Notice that there is no row for `00:01` for `CAD`, the final result should look like this:

**joined_df**

```text
minute_time | currency | val. | someOtherVal
------------------------------------
00:00       | USD      |  4   | 20
00:01       | USD      |  5   | 12
00:00       | CAD      |  4   | 14
00:01       | CAD      |  5   | NULL // so in the final result CAD 00:01 should be there
```

This would have been very simple if there was no currency, it would have just been a left join like:

```sql
SELECT a.*, b.* from minute_df LEFT JOIN data_df b on a.minute_pt = b.minute_pt
```

The currency case makes it tricky when `data_df` doesn't have a record for some `minute_pt`, but in the final result we want every single `minute_pt` from `minute_df` for every single `currency` in `data_df`.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: *we want every single minute_pt from minute_df for every single currency in data_df* - you've given yourself the answer right there: you want to left join all the currency data (right side) onto a combining of all the distinct minutes with distinct currencies (left side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cross join `minute_df` with distinct currencies from `data_df` to get all associations  (`minute_time`, `currency`) before doing left join like this:

```py
spark.createDataFrame(
    [("00:00", "USD", 20), ("00:01", "USD", 12), ("00:00", "CAD", 14)],
    ["minute_time", "currency", "someOtherVal"]
).createOrReplaceTempView("data_df")

spark.createDataFrame([("00:00", 4), ("00:01", 5)], ["minute_time", "val"]).createOrReplaceTempView("minute_df")

spark.sql("""
WITH minute_currency_df AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    minute_df
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT currency FROM data_df)
)

SELECT  m.*, d.someOtherVal 
FROM    minute_currency_df m
LEFT JOIN  data_df d
ON      m.minute_time = d.minute_time
AND     m.currency = d.currency
""").show()

#+-----------+---+--------+------------+
#|minute_time|val|currency|someOtherVal|
#+-----------+---+--------+------------+
#|      00:01|  5|     CAD|        null|
#|      00:01|  5|     USD|          12|
#|      00:00|  4|     USD|          20|
#|      00:00|  4|     CAD|          14|
#+-----------+---+--------+------------+
```